# Firebase auth callback for user data updates - how to keep user data up do date in UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, authentication

bellow I have the standard way of setting the user state to `currentuser` that is returned from `onAuthStateChanged`. I would like a useEffect hook that is called when any update to user's info is made. I cant seam to figure out how to do that.

My current solution is to manually trigger a function that sets `checkingStatus` to `true` so that the bellow useEffect runs again.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("change")
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentuser) => {
      setUser(currentuser);
      setCheckingStatus(false);
    });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, [aucheckingStatus]);
```

Is there a way to listen to any changes made to user and then trigger a useEffect that updates the user state ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `auth.currentUser` actually contains up to date user data, for reasons beyond my comprehension you cant actually trigger a `useEffect` using `auth.currentUser` because ReactJS is not recognising the change, also setting the user state to `auth.currentUser` will also not work, but for some reason if you spread `auth.currentUser` React will properly update state.

As a result my solution is to spread `auth.currentUser` after I finish a profile update or other user data related actions.

```js
const updateUserProfile = (profileData) => {
  updateProfile(auth.currentUser, profileData).then((res) => {
    // Success
    setUser({...auth.currentUser})
  }).catch((error) => {
    // Fail
  })
}

useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentuser) => {
    setUser(currentuser);
  });

  return () => {
    unsubscribe();
  };
}, []);
```